# Dockerfile and Entrypoint["gunicorn" ]

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

this is my Dockerfile content :

> FROM python:stretch
>
> RUN pip install  pyjwt
>
> RUN pip install flask
>
> RUN pip install gunicorn
>
> RUN pip install pytest
>
> ADD . /app/
>
> WORKDIR /app
>
> ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn","-b", ":8080","main:APP"]

I run this command : **docker build --no-cache -t test - <Dockerfile**  and it's ok but when i try this command  :   **docker run -v /app --env-file=.env_file -p 80:8080 test** i have this error : **docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: "gunicorn": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.**

the file main.py is in the same folder as a Dockerfile

**How can I solve this problem?**

Comment: It looks to me like you're copying your app into the `/app` directory in the docker image/container, but then when you run it, you mount a volume over the top of it.  That would hide whatever's in `/app` in the image.  What do you think the `-v /app` is buying you when you run your container? What happens if you leave that off of the command?

Comment: i replace   " docker build --no-cache -t test - <Dockerfile "    with "docker build --tag test   ."  and it's OK, thank you

Comment: A search engine lead me to this page because (it turns out) my autocorrect trimmed off the "g" in gunicorn, causing the wrong package to be installed